# can we have disjoint ideals in the same ring?

Tags: ring-theory

That is, disjoint insofar as they contain nothing in common other than the identity element.  Is this possible?

I ask because I have seen ascending and descending chains of ideals (wrt. set inclusion), and the simplest examples of non-trivial ideals (subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ consisting of multiples of a given number) are never completely disjoint.  For instance $5\mathbb{Z}$ and $7\mathbb{Z}$ contains all numbers that are both multiples of five and seven.

I'm sorry if this question seems silly, but I have not taken ring theory yet.

Comment: Think about ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ where $m$ is composite.

Answer (score 1):

Take $R=F_2\times F_2$ and the ideals $F_2\times\{0\}$ and $\{0\}\times F_2$.

($F_2$ is the field of two elements.)

Comment: I should start keeping a tally of how often I use this four element ring as an example/counterexample ...